# Stop auto scroll down in OS X terminal

Tags: terminal, macos

Is there a way to temporarily stop the terminal from automatically scrolling down when new output is output to the terminal?

Comment: How about pressing `Control-S`? I don't have `OS X` at hand but it work in other `Unixes`.

Comment: Tried it just now. Doesn’t seem to have any effect.

Comment: it worked for me! control-x not command-x.

Comment: Do you have `stty`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I don't know what stty is.  I should mention though that I am ssh'ed into a linux machine while trying to stop the scrolling out.  neither `control-S` or `control-x` have any effect.

Comment: How do I tell?  I'm just running iterm from my iMac.  if I type du -h, which takes a while to run, doing control-x halts the scrolling of output until I hit the return key.

Comment: @jmh oh you are using iterm?  I’m using terminal

Comment: Tried it on iterm also just now. Ctrl x has no effect.

Comment: I just tried with terminal and it still worked.  I'm not connected to anything or logged into another machine. I'm just testing this from my iMac.

Comment: lol..  What a strange difference!

Comment: lol yeah I just tried it on my other mac also and no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your command into more or less.  du -h | less
This gives you a page at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Just scroll a line or two upward. The terminal only scrolls down automatically when you're already at the bottom. (This works in many other terminals as well, not just Terminal.app.)